# What is the best approach for getting context to estabish icon for swipe to delete

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a recyclerview within a fragment. Working to implement a swipetodelete for rows within the recycler view.  When using some example code for the swipe, it is looking to establish context for the ContextCompat.getDrawable() method.  What is the best way to set the context?

The problem line of code for setting the icon in the Swipe To Delete code is

```
icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mAdapter.getContext(),R.drawable.baseline_delete_sweep_white_24dp));
```

**Here is the CheckInListAdapter code for the recyclerview.**

```
package com.example.checkingin;


import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.util.List;

import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

public class CheckInListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckInListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private int checkInListLayout;
    private List<CheckInTable> checkInList;
    private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private CheckInTable mRecentlyDeletedItem;
    private int mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition;

    public CheckInListAdapter(int layoutId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CheckInListAdapter: ");
        checkInListLayout = layoutId;
    }

    public void setCheckInList(List<CheckInTable> allCheckIn) {
        checkInList = allCheckIn;
        Log.i(TAG, "setCheckInList: ");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    //public Context getContext() {return this.getContext();}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return checkInList == null ? 0 : checkInList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: ");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder checkInListViewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return checkInListViewHolder;

    }
    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        mRecentlyDeletedItem = checkInList.get(position);
        mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition = position;

        checkInList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        showUndoSnackbar();
    }
    //private getContext(Context context) {
    //    context = this.getContext();
    //    return context;
   // }
    private void showUndoSnackbar() {
        //View view = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.check_in_recent_recycler_view);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                .make(coordinatorLayout, "Item was removed from the list.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        //Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.checkin_recent_swipetodelete,
        //        Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setAction(R.string.snack_bar_undo, v -> undoDelete());
        snackbar.show();
    }

    private void undoDelete() {
        checkInList.add(mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition,
                mRecentlyDeletedItem);
        notifyItemInserted(mRecentlyDeletedItemPosition);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView checkInLastDateTime = holder.checkInLastDateTime;
        TextView checkInTitle = holder.checkInTitle;
        TextView checkInDestinationName = holder.checkInDestinationName;
        TextView checkInComments = holder.checkInComments;
        holder.checkInEditButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_edit);
        holder.checkInResendButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);


        Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: ");

        checkInLastDateTime.setText(checkInList.get(listPosition).getCheckInLastDateTime());
        checkInTitle.setText(checkInList.get(listPosition).getCheckInTitle());
        checkInDestinationName.setText(checkInList.get(listPosition).getCheckInDestinationName());
        checkInComments.setText(checkInList.get(listPosition).getCheckInComments());

        ImageView checkInEditButton = holder.checkInEditButton;
        ImageView checkInResendButton = holder.checkInResendButton;

        ImageButton editCheckInButton = checkInEditButton.findViewById(R.id.checkInEditButton);
        ImageButton resendCheckInButton = checkInResendButton.findViewById(R.id.checkInResendButton);

        editCheckInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //put in edit check in logic
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick: for edit check in");
                //put in logic to switch to activity for add/edit checkin

            }
        }
        );
        resendCheckInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //put in resend logic
                Log.i(TAG, "onClick:  for resend");
                //add logic to store new check in table row and verify refresh of check in rows
                // on check in recent list


            }
        });

        }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView checkInLastDateTime;
        TextView checkInTitle;
        TextView checkInDestinationName;
        TextView checkInComments;
        ImageView checkInEditButton;
        ImageView checkInResendButton;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.i(TAG, "ViewHolder: ");
            checkInLastDateTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInLastDateTime);
            checkInTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInTitle);
            checkInDestinationName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInDestinationName);
            checkInComments = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInComments);
            checkInEditButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInEditButton);
            checkInResendButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkInResendButton);
            //recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Swipe To Delete code**

```
package com.example.checkingin;



import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;

import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;


import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class CheckInRequestSwipeToDelete extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private CheckInListAdapter mAdapter;
    private Drawable icon;
    private final ColorDrawable background;




    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        mAdapter.deleteItem(position);
    }
    public CheckInRequestSwipeToDelete(CheckInListAdapter adapter) {
        super(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
        mAdapter = adapter;
        icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mAdapter.getContext(),R.drawable.baseline_delete_sweep_white_24dp));
        background = new ColorDrawable(Color.RED);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        // used for up and down movements
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX,
                dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        int backgroundCornerOffset = 20;
        if (dX > 0) { // Swiping to the right
            background.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(),
                    itemView.getLeft() + ((int) dX) + backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getBottom());

        } else if (dX < 0) { // Swiping to the left
            background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + ((int) dX) - backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        } else { // view is unSwiped
            icon.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            background.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        background.draw(c);
        int iconMargin = (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        int iconTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        int iconBottom = iconTop + icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (dX > 0) { // Swiping to the right
            int iconLeft = itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin;
            int iconRight = itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin + icon.getIntrinsicWidth();

            icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);

            background.setBounds(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(),
                    itemView.getLeft() + ((int) dX) + backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getBottom());
        } else if (dX < 0) { // Swiping to the left
            int iconLeft = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin - icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int iconRight = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin;
            icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);

            background.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + ((int) dX) - backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
        } else { // view is unSwiped
            background.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        background.draw(c);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass icon Drawable via constructor, it's better instead of getting context from adapter